# What is meant the minifyEnabled false in the release block in the gradle.build file

Tags: android

Perhaps my question seems a simple question and duplicate. But it is for me an important question. I  have android studio 1.3 and when I create a new default project and then when I open the `build.gradle(Module:app)` , I see the following code in part of `build.gradle(Module:app)`file. Also you should know that when I compile my project, android studio makes two `apk` files that both are as the `debug` mode. in the following code is used from the `release` block and the `minifyEnabled` is `false`. Now I want to know that despite these conditions, when I compile my project, does the android studio use from `proguard` really? Thank you in advanced.

```
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
```

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Flag `minifyEnabled` stays for ProGuard, and it's turned off by default. So, in default setup both debug and release builds aren't using ProGuard, and parameter `proguardFiles` is effectively ignored

Comment: Thank you. you say `in default setup both debug and release builds aren't using ProGuard`  So, how can I turn on the `ProGuard`?

Comment: You just need to set `minifyEnabled` value to `true`

Comment: I noticed I need to comment out `//proguardFiles ...` line to fix the crash caused by proguard, simply set `minifyEnabled false` not enough.