# What is the minifyEnabled which is declared in gradle file. May I know the meaning and use of following code of block

Tags: android-studio

What is the use and meaning of following code of block?

```
buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
        }
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Using this code block you can configure your `build.gradle` file for proguard implementation and Flag `minifyEnabled` stays for ProGuard, and it's turned off by default.

check this for more informations [minifyEnabled](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32163235/what-is-meant-the-minifyenabled-false-in-the-release-block-in-the-gradle-build-f), [ProGuard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20885725/how-to-use-the-proguard-in-android-studio) and [What is minifyEnabled](https://teamtreehouse.com/community/what-is-minifyenabled)