# Android Proguard : Is minifyEnabled true automatically setting obfuscation to true?

Tags: java, android, proguard, android-proguard

I'm trying to test the App, but I'm wondering which option actually enables obfuscation.

if `minifyEnabled` is `false`, will the files still be obfuscated?

```
buildTypes {
        debug {
          //  minifyEnabled true
            useProguard true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'),
                    'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
        release {
           // minifyEnabled true
           // shrinkResources true
            useProguard true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro',
                    'proguard-fresco.pro.txt'

        }
    }
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32163235/what-is-meant-the-minifyenabled-false-in-the-release-block-in-the-gradle-build-f

Comment: No, proguard is deactivated when the minifyEnabled is set to false. You can turn obfuscation on/off in proguard-rules.pro.

Answer (score -1):

To enable proguard or shrink your code set `minifyEnabled` to `true`

```
android {
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'),
                    'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    ...
}
```

read the documentation at https://developer.android.com/studio/build/shrink-code.html

Comment: if minifyEnabled is false, progurd is completely off?

Comment: you can check the use of useProguard at https://developer.android.com/studio/build/shrink-code.html#gradle-shrinker